# many-to-many relationship from a classes in different assemblies

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, many-to-many, assemblies

I have an entity `Region`:

```
public class Region
{
   public string RegionName { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Language> Languages { get; set; }
}
```

And entity `Language`

```
public class Language
{
   public string LanguageName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create many-to-many between between Regions and Languages, but Language class in a different assembly, so I can not add navigation property to it.

How to create many-to-many relationship to a classes from different assemblies ?
Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Have you added a reference and using statement? Bigger issue will be with your context.

Comment: Yes, I have all the references.

Comment: So what's the error or issue?

Comment: The issue is, that I can not add navigation property to the Language class, cause it is in a different assembly.